# Efficient way to collect HashSet during map operation on some Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have big dataset to transform one structure to another. During that phase I want also collect some info about computed field (quadkeys for given lat/longs). I dont want attach this info to every result row, since it would give a lot of duplication information and memory overhead. All I need is to know which particular quadkeys are touched by given coordinates. If there are any way to do it within one job to not iterate dataset twice?

```scala
def load(paths: Seq[String]): (Dataset[ResultStruct], Dataset[String]) = {
    val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true")
      .schema(schema)
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .load(paths:_*)
      .as[InitialStruct]
    val qkSet = mutable.HashSet.empty[String]

    val result = df.map(c => {
      val id = c.id
      val points = toPoints(c.geom)
      points.foreach(p => qkSet.add(Quadkey.get(p.lat, p.lon, 6).getId))
      createResultStruct(id, points)
    })
    return result, //some dataset created from qkSet's from all executors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use accumulators

```
class SetAccumulator[T] extends AccumulatorV2[T, Set[T]] {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  private val items = new ConcurrentHashMap[T, Boolean]

  override def isZero: Boolean = items.isEmpty
  override def copy(): AccumulatorV2[T, Set[T]] = {
    val other = new SetAccumulator[T]
    other.items.putAll(items)
    other
  }
  override def reset(): Unit = items.clear()
  override def add(v: T): Unit = items.put(v, true)
  override def merge(
        other: AccumulatorV2[T, Set[T]]): Unit = other match {
    case setAccumulator: SetAccumulator[T] => items.putAll(setAccumulator.items)
  }
  override def value: Set[T] = items.keys().asScala.toSet
}

val df = Seq("foo", "bar", "foo", "foo").toDF("test")

val acc = new SetAccumulator[String]
spark.sparkContext.register(acc)

df.map {
  case Row(str: String) =>
    acc.add(str)
    str
}.count()

println(acc.value)
```

Prints

```
Set(bar, foo)
```

Note that `map` itself is lazy so something like `count` etc. is needed to actually force the calculation. Depending on the real use-case, another option would be to cache the data frame and just using plain SQL functions `df.select("test").distinct()`